# Does any one know what type/name these types of cables/wires are called?

Tags: wire

I've come across a [YouTube video and at 2:22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgDD0DgwCaI&lc=UgxkhD5euSXXsRBAJqV4AaABAg.9mwl_holfeN9n1Ok8hlSnD&ab_channel=Bj%C3%B6rnLorenzen) there is a clip with extremely thin wires. These wires are coated with something which stops them from shorting out. Any name for such wires?

Here is the screen shot of the wire:

[image]

What would be the gage of the wire?

Comment: Looks like magnet wire or enamel coated wire to me.

Comment: Something like 32AWG is reasonably thin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [enamelled wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_wire). Basically it's a thin wire that is coated with an isolator. You can strip the coating with heat from a soldering iron. It's useful for reworking PCBs, because the small size allows it to be soldered directly to traces (once the solder mask is stripped of course). It's best to use it with a [wiring pencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiring_pencil) like this:

[image]